# How do I add a <div> after every field element on the node edit form?

Tags: theming, forms

There are two approaches that have failed:

1. In the theme, add a theme hook for the node edit form.  Then, create a template file for the node edit form.  This won't work for my case, because the form is rendered in the template file with drupal_render_children, and therefore the contents of the form are not reachable within the template file--I need to add the divs in between the form elements.
2. Use hook_form_alter.  This won't work for my case, because you have to target a specific form item.  The users may, for example, add a new node field after I hand it off to them, and my existing hook_form_alter wouldn't have a way to catch it.

What I want to do is simple; in between every element on the node edit form, insert a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` to separate them.

Or, I could add the "clearfix" class to the existing div containers around the form elements.

Do we have a solution for either method?

[EDIT] Here is the solution using hook_form_alter():

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (preg_match('/node_form$/', $form_id)) {
    $language = $form['language']['#value'];
    foreach ($form_state['field'] as $field => $field_contents) {    
      $form[$field][$language]['#suffix'] = '<div class="clearfix></div>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using `hook_form_alter` for each Field add `#suffix => '<div class="clearfix"></div>"` to the existing FAPI array for the Field. I would just hard code it per field.

If you need to you could make a for loop and walk through the FIELDs so you dont hardcode the fields by hand ... If you were more crazy you could use an `#after_build` function too on the `$form` or set 1 per Field element as needed if you run into problems.

Comment: Yes, using hook_form_alter() worked for me.